# Searching value for a given key in a HashMap returns null

Tags: java, android, hashmap

This below result is my `HashMap` value which I fill that by loop clause

```
private Map<String, String> days = new HashMap<>();

0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4952} "2131689719" -> "2016-11-25"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4953} "2131689683" -> "2016-11-26"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4954} "2131689692" -> "2016-11-27"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4955} "2131689686" -> "2016-11-26"
4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4956} "2131689716" -> "2016-12-01"
```

and now, when I try to search a value for a given key such as :

```
days.get("2131689719")
```

I get `null`

#### UPDATED:

```
int day         = 0;
int dateOfWeeks = 10;
for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(food_list_values[i])).setText(dayOfWeeks[day]);
    days.put(String.valueOf((findViewById(food_list_values[i])).getId()), foodList.get(dateOfWeeks).getDate());
    day++;
    dateOfWeeks++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you populate that map? Not just a `toString()` result on it ...

Comment: That is maybe because you are populating a scoped copy of the map... dont be shy! post more code!! it is for free !! :)

Comment: @RO_engineer post updated

Comment: Are you sure the days map does not get a new instance?

Comment: Are you sure `dateOfWeeks` should be intialized to 10?

Comment: I guess the value which could have inserted for "2131689719" would be null..

Comment: @RajasubaSubramanian no, its not null, value of that is: `2016-11-25`

Comment: Also this is always true (findViewById(food_list_values[i])).getId() == food_list_values[i], unless you get a null pointer. So why don't you just use food_list_values[i] and SparseArray instead of Map?

Comment: You should write up a [MCVE] of the problem behaviour you are seeing. As it is, you're just asking strangers to guess why your (incomplete) code might be wrong.

Comment: Can you please add your sample get code?

Comment: I guess the value you pass for get must be some int... So, can you please share the code on get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could have added the value as `String` and try to obtain it as  an `Integer` which could have caused this problem. Please try the following

```
days.get(Integer.toString(findViewById(food_list_values[i])).getId()));
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the Map days is having only one element `null, <last date>`

this here is not correct

```
findViewById(food_list_values[i]))
```

findViewById is normally using R.id resources that you define in th Android application,

Comment: no sir, its wrong, `findViewById(food_list_values[i]))` return object as `textview` class, for example: `android.widget.TextView{ae55e40 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0f00fa app:id/value_7}`